# What's Syntax about this line of Ternary Operator

Tags: c++, syntax, conditional-operator

I trying many time to understand how to work or what's syntax code it ?

```
greatest=(a>b&&a>c)?a:(b>c)?b : c;
```

I know the main syntax of Ternary Operator

but in greatest i don't know how come it

- the Required I want to anyone explain me that and give me syntax of them .

thanks.

Comment: If you already know the syntax of the ternary operator, what is it that you need more explanation on?

Comment: Formatting the expression might help.

Comment: Why would you want to write something like `greatest=(a>b&&a>c)?a:(b>c)?b : c;` in the first place? I mean, if you were *initializing* a variable I *might* see why, but that's not even what you are doing. Why not just write it out as more readable `if` / `else` statements? The compiler won't care, the resulting code will probably be identical, but it will be a *lot* more readable to your fellow humans.

Comment: @JesperJuhl: even `std::max` instead of manual `if` or ternary operator ;-)

Comment: `auto greatest = std::max({a, b, c});` is clearer anyway.

Comment: @Jarod42 naturally. That makes perfect sense.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This operator is essentially similar to these if-else statements

```
if ( a > b && a > c )
{
    greatest = a;
}
else if ( b > c )
{
    greatest = b;
}
else
{ 
    greatest = c;
}
```

To make the expression with two nested conditional operators more clear use parentheses

```
greatest = ( a > b && a > c ? a: (  b > c ? b : c ) );
```

You could use the standard algorithm `std::max` instead of the expression with the two nested conditional operators. For example

```
greatest = std::max( { a, b, c } );
```